# prevent javascript from loading more than once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I was trying to run on scroll load more but I want it to only run once. The code below keeps on running each time the scroll reaches bottom of page.
I need to add something to the code

```
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -   $(window).height() && x==24 ){
```

but i don't know what to add to make it so that it only runs once or so that the code is prevented from running more than once.

```
 <script>


    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -   $(window).height() && x==24 ){



   });
 });
 </script>
```

so basically my question is how to prevent javascript from running more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If the `scroll` event is only needed to call the function once, you can then remove the `scroll` event from `$(window)` using `.off()` within `if` statement.

```css
body {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="div1">div </div>
<script>
  x = 24;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("scroll.once", function() {

      if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && x == 24) {

        $(window).off("scroll.once");
        $("#div1").append(123);

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: let me try and see if it works

Comment: where would i add this code. would I add to the if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -   $(window).height() && x==24 ){

Comment: @letsworktogether See updated post, using `$.Callbacks("once")`

Comment: @letsworktogether _"let me try and see if it works"_ Does approach at stacksnippets return expected result?

Comment: i think it does. I like your code but its just to complex. I appreciate what u did but i found a better solution. One that was simple. See update above. Thanks alot.

Comment: @letsworktogether If you have resolved issue you can post and accept an Answer to your own Question, see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple but not too elegant solution where you can add a `boolean flag` before the function and `check` the `boolean state` before executing the codes in your function. Change to the desire `boolean state` after the first call of your function so that you can prevent it from being called again. For example:

```
<script>
  var called = false;

  function myFunc(){
    if (!called){
      //your code here
      called = !called;
    }
  }
</script>
```

It will not be the best answer out there but still, hope it helps =)